# Eliminar valores de un diccionario en python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Estoy tratando de eliminar progresivamente valores de un diccionario, por ejemplo:

```
diccionario = {1:['perro', 'gato'], 2:['auto', 'moto']}
```

y busco llegar a:

```
diccionario = {1:[], 2:['auto', 'moto']}.
```

De momento se me ocurrió lo siguiente

```
    for clave, valores in diccionario.items():
        for valor in valores:
            if clave == 1:
                del diccionario[clave][valores.index(valor)]
```

Pero solo elimina el primer valor de la clave 1, es decir:

```
diccionario = {1:['gato'], 2:['auto', 'moto']}
```

Comment: No se entiende bien el por qué el bucle interno para eliminar "progresivamente". ¿No es más sencillo asignar la lista vacía a todas las claves? O sea `diccionario = {k: [] for k,v in diccionario.items()}`

Comment: Por otro lado, revisa el ejemplo. El diccionario que pones no tiene ninguna clave 0, y en cambio tu bucle compara con 0, por lo que al final no elimina ninguno. Tu ejemplo no es verificable.

Comment: Necesito trabajar con el string mas largo de la lista y luego eliminarlo para que no lo vuelva a tener en cuenta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se entiende muy bien la necesidad de lo que se pide, pero supongo que se debe a que has tratado de simplificar al mínimo el ejemplo y que en tu caso real tenga más sentido eso de ir eliminando elementos de una lista iterando en un bucle.

En todo caso, el problema ocurre porque en general no es buena idea modificar la lista por la que se está iterando. Cuando haces algo como:

```
l = ["perro", "gato"]

for animal in l:
  del l[l.index(animal)]
```

Ocurre que tras la primera iteración en que se elimina "perro", la lista ha menguado su longitud en 1, y cuando `for` intente seguir iterando en ella verá que ya ha procesado un elemento y que no hay más, así que terminará el bucle. Es decir, se ha saltado el gato.

Modificar la longitud de un iterable mientras se itera por él siempre causa problemas.

Una solución puede ser iterar por una copia del que se está modificando. En tu caso sería así:

```
for clave, valores in diccionario.items():
    for valor in valores.copy():
        if clave == 1:
            del diccionario[clave][valores.index(valor)]
```

Observa el `valores.copy()`. Eso crea otra lista copia de la origina, y es esta segunda lista por la que itera el bucle. Esta lista no se ve afectada por que borres elementos de `valores`. Por otro lado en lugar de `del` para eliminar el elemento, podrías haber usado `valores.pop(valores.index(valor))`

Otra opción puede ser, en lugar de borrar elementos directamente sobre una lista, crear otra lista nueva en la que se copian todos los que había en la original, excepto el que se quiere borrar. Por ejemplo en tu caso:

```
for clave, valores in diccionario.items():
    for valor in valores:
        if clave == 1:
            diccionario[clave] = [v for v in valores if v!=valor]
```

Y aún habría otras formas de hacerlo. Cuál es la mejor depende del caso de uso particular, por lo que quizás sería conveniente que editaras la pregunta para poner código que esté más cercano al problema concreto en que estás trabajando.

Comment: Me funciono con la primera solución, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes llegar al resultado querido de la siguiente manera:

```
diccionario = {1:['perro', 'gato'], 2:['auto', 'moto']}
for clave in diccionario:
    if clave == 1:
        diccionario[clave] = []
```

En tu fórmula condicional, no usabas referencia al valor, por lo que no necesitas el método *.items* del diccionario, que te proporciona *clave, valor* del diccionario.
De la misma manera, el segundo bucle *for* no es necesario, solo iteras sobre la clave del diccionario en tu condicional.
Y para finalizar, la parte *diccionario[clave]* te permite acceder al valor para modificarlo y en ese caso borrar la lista.

Por otra parte, mencionas un borrado progresivo del diccionario, puede que te refieras a borrar los valores uno tras uno, por lo tanto, tendrías que usar la función *enumerate()* que te permite iterar de la siguiente manera:

```
for i,clave in enumerate(diccionario):
    if clave == i+1:
        diccionario[clave] = []
```

De esta manera, en cada bucle del *for*, borras los valores que corresponden a un elemento del diccionario.